# How to deploy an ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have an ASP.Net website that I built in a computer science class.  I built it in Visual Studio and the solution is on my local drive.  How would I deploy this to a real website?

Comment: Firstly, did you Google ? You can easily find this on Google and still if you have any problems you can post on SO.

Comment: You can get some inputs @ http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030806.htm

Comment: @Pratik whether something can be found on google has nothing to do with whether it should be part of SO.

Comment: @jball i just meant it is easy to find on google and i also think that it would be a duplicate question on SO

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do a few things.

1. You will need to get a hosting account that supports ASP.NET
2. From there you can use the "Publish" option from within Visual Studio under the "Build" menu option to push out a copy of the site.

When publishing you should publish in release mode.

Comment: For the last step, you can also simply use an FTP client to copy your files. I run a number of sites and, for a few of them, this is just easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

Get hosting that supports the version of .NET and ASP.NET you have used and copy the files over.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that already you have an IIS application and web folder set up on a web server somewhere, the simplest method goes like this:

1. In Visual Studio, right-click on the web application project, and click `Publish`.
2. Select `File System` as the publish method.
3. Select a target location. This is where the publishable files will be placed. Use `c:\pub` or something similar.
4. Hit `Publish`
5. Once the publish operation is done, copy everything in `c:\pub` (or whatever target folder you used in step 3) to your web folder on the web server. Depending on your server accessibility, you may need to do this via FTP.

You might also investigate [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if your server supports it.

If you don't already have server space, you'll need to find a good hosting provider that supports ASP.NET. [Google has many suggestions](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+hosting).